# Check if grid class exists on page using Smarty in CS-Cart

Tags: smarty, cs-cart

I want to add a class to the header or body automatically based on the existance of a grid class on that page.

Is there a way to get all the grid classes for the current page so that I can cycle through to check?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `views/block_manager/render/grid.tpl` file by creating the `[THEME]/templates/addons/[YOUR_ADDON]/overrides/views/block_manager/render/grid.tpl` file and then you can use `$grid.user_class` to check whether a class exists or not and implement your desired behavior.